# Passing a date string from a C# controller to a Javascript function is altering the string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue where my controller is passing ViewData in to a view, which is then consumed by a javascript function. the ViewData is a date formatted into a string. Yet once passed into Javascript the string turns into '0.021978021978021976' rather than 'mm/dd/yy' fomrat. What would cause this?
Here is the code in the controller that is generating this view data.

```
        string dateString;
        string cultureConfigKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceCulture"];
        DateTime? lastEntryDate = null;
        DataSet dSet = DataHelper.Measurements_GetLastMeasurement(userSession.UserIDNative);                
        foreach (DataRow dr in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            lastEntryDate = (DateTime?)dr["When"];                                 
        }

        // format date based on culture and convert it to string
        if (cultureConfigKey == "en" )
        {                
            ViewData["DateString"] = dateString = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", lastEntryDate);
        }
```

With in the view I reference the ViewData as followed

```
        @
        {
            var dateString = ViewData["DateString"];
            // calling @dateString in this point shows the string in proper format
        }

        // further down in the view I pass the dateString into the following function which generates some markup that is supposed to prinout out this date string with in it. 
        buildNotification(@dateString);

        // the above function is built in an outside .js file here is its declaration 
        function buildNotification(dateString){
            $('.stats-chartsView').before(
            '<div class="noData-popup">' +
                '<p class="noData-Img"></p>' +
                '<p class="no-data alert">' + CHART_DATA_NOTIFICATION + '<span>'+ dateString +'</span></p>' +
            '</div>'
            );
        }

        Thanks!
```

Comment: `ViewData["DateString"]` is typed as an `object`. Is there some disconnect between the implicit conversion between MVC and JavaScript? Would it be enough to just set `var dateString = ViewData["DateString"].ToString();` instead?

Comment: I'm actually handling the conversion to string in the controller before passing it to the view in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you are not passing this parameter in your JS function with quotes and treating it like a string.

```
buildNotification(@dateString);
```

should be

```
buildNotification('@dateString');
```

Your JS function is seeing 08/04/2013 and most likely doing the long division of those three integers.

Comment: Why is it that when the variable is initially stored is does not get stored with the quotes?...I just waisted sooo much time trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Stavros_S This is one of the good reasons you have to split your javascript into seperate js files.

Comment: @asawyer I hate the fact that I have to put some Javascript in the view, but what is the best way to pass Variables from razor into Javascript with out making the function call from the view